Deep Link With Adjust
As you may be aware, Google will soon shut down Firebase Dynamic Link. As a Unity developer, I plan to replace it with Adjust's custom links.
I'm attempting to replicate the functionality of Firebase Dynamic Link. From what I understand, Adjust captures deep links with Unity's Deep Link. However, I couldn't find any event in Adjust to listen to that. Therefore, I need to know how to read a deep link, regardless of whether it's on Android or not, and whether it's deferred or standard, irrespective of the case. Is there a way to read deep links with Adjust?
I've set the scheme, made changes to the manifest, and read the deep link with Unity. However, Adjust does not trigger the deferredLinkCallBack if it is standard, and there are no other callbacks related to the deep link. Adjust attempts to call "appWillOpenUrl" instead of providing the URL. I am expecting to read the deep link using Adjust's callback.
